# Problems with limits and projections in ggOceanmaps

Tags: r, ggplot2, mapping

I have been trying to make a bathymetry map using the ggOceanMaps package in R. I get an Arctic stereographicmap when using

```
basemap(limits = 60, bathymetry=TRUE)
```

but I get the following error whenever I try to use specific limits:

```
basemap(limits = c(-20, 20, 40, 59))

Using lon and lat as longitude and latitude columns, respectively.
projection transformed from +init=epsg:4326 to +init=epsg:3995
Error in sp::CRS(SRS_string = "EPSG:4326") : 
  no arguments in initialization list
```

This is all the code I have used:

```
install.packages(c("ggOceanMapsData", "ggOceanMaps"), 
                 repos = c("https://cloud.r-project.org", 
"https://mikkovihtakari.github.io/drat")
    )

devtools::install_github("MikkoVihtakari/ggOceanMapsData") # required by ggOceanMaps
devtools::install_github("MikkoVihtakari/ggOceanMaps")

library(ggplot2)  
library(rgdal)  
library(raster)  
library(ggsn)  
library(rworldmap) 
library(rworldxtra)
library(icesDatras)
library(icesAdvice)
library(usethis)
library(testthat)
library(devtools)
library(sp)
library(FLCore)
library(maps)
library(ggthemes)
library(rlang)
library(rgeos)
library(raster)
library(viridis)
library(maptools)
library(MASS)
library(stats)
library(rgbif)
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(plotly)
library(hrbrthemes)
library(oce)
library(ggOceanMaps)
library(ggOceanMapsData)
library(gghighlight)
library(ggtext)
library(ggridges)
library(ggpubr)
library(gsw)
library(raster)
library(rasterVis)
library(viridis)
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(marelac)
library(plot3D)
library(wql)
library(ggsn)  
library(ggspatial)
require(ggmap)
library(knitr)

#########

basemap(limits=60)
basemap(limits = c(-20, 20, 40, 59))
```

Comment: Hi Maria, this is very likely a bug stemming from me trying to fix a mystical bug on Solaris CRAN told me about. I think issue is that I am trying to roll to PROJ6 and the old PROJ4 does not seem to always work together with the new system. Therefore, there is a mismatch with ggOceanMaps and ggOceanMapsData. Solution: delete ggOceanMapsData and ggOceanMaps. Reinstall both from GitHub under R >= 4.0 (I think). See here: https://github.com/MikkoVihtakari/ggOceanMaps/issues/4

Comment: You may open a new issue on Github if this does not help.

Comment: Also, FYI in the future, if a package is behaving differently to the documentation on your computer, it's quite likely a bug. You should file these under issues for each package (on Github or wherever the devs want). SO is useful to find solutions (i.e. in case you wanted to do something with the package that was not documented). I found this post by luck while Googling. On GitHub, I am more likely to see issues you may have with the package and respond.